# Multi form web application design

Tags: delphi, web-applications, user-interface, web-application-design

When porting a classic ClientServer Application to a web applciation (by totally rewriting it from scratch) a typical qusstion is

"How do I manage the multi form scenario i am used to?"

In a Windows (Delphi) application, such in my case, the user is using the application accessing more forms in parallel or one at a time but all of them are displayed on screen simultaenously (may be someone is minimized, othres are modal, ....).

In a web application the options are:

1) use different browser tabs

2) Have a kind of Navbar on the left and populate a full screen (vull viewport) "Panel" that contains the "form"

3) Have a "simulation of the classic behavior" as supported by ExtJS (try [this example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/window/window.html) where on a same webpage multiple forms exist and they are movable like on a windows desktop

(3) is strange and it reminds me of RDP

Which alternatives to (1) and (2)?

Answer (score 1):

It's important to get your basic knowledge about web-applications straight first. A desktop application has total control about what forms are shown and what happens on/to them. Web applications communicate *only* using requests coming in from a web-browser and responses sent back. This can be either by normal navigation to a URL, or by Ajax calls.

There are a number of options that try to *translate* between the form-designer way of doing things and the request-response nature of the web, but in my personal opinion, this will almost always give a result of lesser quality and will require you to delve into the translation-layer to get this or that strange artefact of it out of the way. So I would suggest to get into HTML and CSS and javascript and decent webpage design as well as building a HTTP Delphi back-end.

See also this list: [What Web Application Framework for Delphi is recommended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793112/what-web-application-framework-for-delphi-is-recommended)

(Disclaimer: I'm behind the [xxm](http://xxm.sf.net/) project)

Comment: Hello, that distinction is clear to me, but after some research I reliazed (even if cannot be 100% sure) that for my needs using a stateful app (like UniGUI/Raudus to mention some of the frameworks lsted in the post you linked). I know that it is a "bad"/non academic" approach but I plan to have lots of on premise installations (so few users using the app simultaneously), the others will be served by a cloud farm. I undesrtand that to write apps like Facebook or Ebay this approach makes no sense, but when the app is tied to forms and navigation forms logic this approach is suitable.

Comment: So my question is: considering I plan to use a "VCL for the web approach", how to manage multiple forms?